# How to use Timer and await together in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous

I have a code like below:

```
Timer(Duration(seconds: 5),(){
   print("This is printed after 5 seconds.");
});
print("This is printed when Timer ends");
```

How can I use "await" in this case? I want when Timer ends then run next code below Timer. I used Future.delayed(), it can do it but I can't skip the delay time in Future.delayed() like in Timer(). Because i want to skip the delay time if the condition is true. Because I want to skip the delay time if the condition is true. If I use Future.delayed(), it doesn't have cancel() method like Timer().
Please tell me the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve what you need. You can use [Completer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Completer-class.html) and `Future.any` like this:

```
import 'dart:async';

Completer<void> cancelable = Completer<void>();

// auxiliary function for convenience and better code reading
void cancel() => cancelable.complete();

Future.any(<Future<dynamic>>[
  cancelable.future,
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5)),
]).then((_) {
  if (cancelable.isCompleted) {
    print('This is print when timer has been canceled.');
  } else {
    print('This is printed after 5 seconds.');
  }
});

// line to test cancel, comment to test timer completion
Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)).then((_) => cancel());
```

Basically we are creating two futures one is a delayed and another one is cancelable future. And we are waiting for the first one that completes using `Future.any`.

The other option is to use [CancelableOperation](https://pub.dev/documentation/async/latest/async/CancelableOperation-class.html) or [CancelableCompleter](https://pub.dev/documentation/async/latest/async/CancelableCompleter-class.html).

For example:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:async/async.dart';

Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)).then((_) => cancel());

var cancelableDelay = CancelableOperation.fromFuture(
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5)),
  onCancel: () => print('This is print when timer has been canceled.'),
);

// line to test cancel, comment to test timer completion
Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)).then((_) => cancelableDelay.cancel());

cancelableDelay.value.whenComplete(() {
  print('This is printed after 5 seconds.');
});
```

Here we do practically the same thing as above but with already available classes. We are wrapping `Future.delayed` into `CancelableOperation` so we are able now to cancel that operation (`Future.delayed` in our case).

Another way you can wrap `Timer` into future with `Completer` and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Try Future.delayed instead of Timer

```
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5),(){

                print("This is printed after 5 seconds.");
              });

              print('This is printed when Timer ends');
```

Comment: I know this way, but I can't skip delay time in Future.delayed if condition is true.

Comment: You can give delay time according to your condition. For ex., If the condition is true then delay time will be 0 and if condition will false then delay time will be 5 seconds

Answer (score 2):

```dart
Timer(Duration(seconds: 5),(){
   print("This is printed after 5 seconds.");
   printWhenTimerEnds();
});

void printWhenTimerEnds(){
 print("This is printed when Timer ends");
}
```

When you wish to skip the timer just call timer cancel and the printWhenTimerEnds() method

Answer (score 0):

You can combine Timer with [Completer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Completer-class.html) to complete it from your Timer and `await` on `Completer.future` like this:

```dart
final completer = Completer<bool>();
final timer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 5),(){
  print("This is printed after 5 seconds.");
  if (!completer.isCompleted) {
    completer.complete(false);
  }
});
final result = await completer.future;
print("This is printed when Timer ends");
print('Is it canceled? $result');
```

Then you can asynchronously cancel the timer somewhere else like this:

```dart
timer.cancel();
if (!completer.isCompleted) {
  completer.complete(true);
}
```

Make sure you do not call `completer.complete()` more than once, because otherwise you will get the "Bad state: Future already completed" exception thrown.